# Redis server on diffrent node using docker on ubuntu 20

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

i want to setup redis cluster on 3 diffrent nodes using docker..can any one suggest the commands or some documents for setup?
i am finding the documents for single node but i want it for multiple nodes
any help would be appriciated
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

so i followed these steps to setup redis cluster on 3 diffrent servers.

add entries in **nano /etc/hosts** file on all the nodes 3 nodes

ip1 hostname1

ip2 hostname2

ip3 hostname3

then save and exit

**on node1**

docker run --name redis-node-1 --hostname hostname1 --net test -p 6379:6379 -p 16379:16379 -d redis redis-server --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes.conf --cluster-node-timeout 5000

**on node2**

docker run --name redis-node-2 --hostname hostname2 --net test -p 6379:6379 -p 16379:16379 -d redis redis-server --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes.conf --cluster-node-timeout 5000

**on node3**

docker run --name redis-node-3 --hostname hostname3 --net test -p 6379:6379 -p 16379:16379 -d redis redis-server --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes.conf --cluster-node-timeout 5000

now once all 3 containers are up run the below command on any node.i am running it on 1st node.

docker exec -it redis-node-1 redis-cli --cluster create ip1:6379 ip2:6379 ip3:6379 --cluster-replicas 0

after the setup is complete verify it with below command

docker exec -it redis-node-1 redis-cli cluster info

This worked for me ..Thank you!

Comment: if u want to setup with replica to 1 instead of 0 then we have to setup 6node cluster